# Java Package Does Not Exist Error

Tags: java, import, package

So there's a folder `/usr/share/stuff` in the root directory

in stuff there are a bunch of java files with `package org.name` definitions at the top

I am running `javac test.java` where `test.java` is in a subdomain

I added `/usr/share/stuff`  to my class path.

and at the top of `test.java` I add `import org.name`

But I get a `package does not exist` error...why?

Comment: Assuming you have compiled the java files into the correct directory (class files are in "/usr/share/stuff/org/name"), you also need to import the actual files or the wildcard into test.java ('import org.name.MyClass' or 'import org.name.*').  If you just do 'import org.name' this error happens (ask me how I know lol)

Comment: is this a Runtime exception or Compile time exception?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Are they in the right subdirectories?

If you put `/usr/share/stuff` on the class path, files defined with `package org.name` should be in `/usr/share/stuff/org/name`.

**EDIT**: If you don't already know this, you should probably read [this doc about understanding classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html#Understanding).

**EDIT 2**: Sorry, I hadn't realised you were talking of Java source files in `/usr/share/stuff`. Not only they need to be in the appropriate sub-directory, but you need to compile them. The `.java` files don't need to be on the *classpath*, but on the *source path*. (The generated `.class` files need to be on the *classpath*.)

You might get away with compiling them if they're not under the right directory structure, but they should be, or it will generate warnings at least. The generated class files will be in the right subdirectories (wherever you've specified `-d` if you have).

You should use something like `javac -sourcepath .:/usr/share/stuff test.java`, assuming you've put the `.java` files that were under `/usr/share/stuff` under `/usr/share/stuff/org/name` (or whatever is appropriate according to their package names).

Comment: Thanks!...This still didn't work though...i've done this but it still says package cannot be found. Is it enough to edit the classpath on the subdomain or does this need to be edited at the root as well?

Answer (score 37):

Just reimport didn't work. Following worked for me.

File -> Invalidate Caches /Restart

Then

Build -> Rebuild Project

That will reimport maven project.

Comment: It was useful. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem, while trying to use a theme packaged as `.jar` in my app, it was working while debugging the app, but it didn't when building/exporting the app.

I solved it by unzipping the `jar`, and manually add its contents to my build folder, resulting in this:

```
project/
   │
   ├── build 
   │   └── classes
   │       ├── pt
   │       │   └── myAppName ... 
   │       └── com
   │           └── themeName ...
   ├── src
   └── lib
```

I don't have the error anymore and my app loads with the intended theme.

Comment: This will work but is the wrong approach; you should instead change your settings to include the .jar inside your .jar when you export.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `org/name` dirs at `/usr/share/stuff` and place your `org.name` package sources at this dir.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem when manually compiling through the command line, my solution was I didn't include the -sourcepath directory so that way all the subdirectory java files would be compiled too!

Answer (score 2):

Right click your maven project
in bottom of the drop down list 
Maven >> reimport

it works for me for the missing dependancyies

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue while using **Kotlin** and have

```
kotlin.incremental=true
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

in the **gradle.properties**, then you need to remove this temporarily to fix the build.

After the successful build, you can again add these properties to speed up the build time while using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following lines in your gradle build file (build.gradle)

```
dependencies { 
     compile files('/usr/share/stuff')
     ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2020 version, that you've most likely got a bug, like the one I got. Tried multiple things, but what helped me is a very simple thing.
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven.
Put a checkmark for Override of Local Repository, but leave the default value. Apply, OK. You can get an error, that's ok. Just press "Reload all Maven Projects" button (two rounded arrows, looks like regular Refresh button) in Maven tab on the right of the screen. Maybe clean and install. Should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question because a bringing a file from one folder to another caused this error for me. The command that fixed it is below. I had the same package in multiple directories, and it was only looking at one of the directories.

So, if it's a Maven project, try `mvn clean install --update-snapshots`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. In intellij idea:

1. Go to project structure
2. Select SDKs and make sure your JDK home path is the real path of your JDK
3. Then use Maven clean install command

This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For me on intelliJ the solution was Right Click on project folder > Run Maven > Reimport Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had issue importing *Kotlin* class in Java class.
Solution was to add `kotlin-android` plugin in module `build.gradle` as:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'         <- this
}

android {
    compileSdk 33
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted folder "target" and this problem solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).