# Can't run Rhino examples: missing package

Tags: java, windows, rhino

This may be a silly question but I've just downloaded [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) on my Windows 7 machine and I'm trying to run some of the examples. However, it says `package org.mozilla.javascript does not exists`

Here's the exact context (running through Git Bash)

```
Mike@WORK-MACHINE /c/users/mike/documents/rhino/examples
$ javac RunScript.java
RunScript.java.7: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
... Error stuff ...
6 errors
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you forgotten to include a directory on your classpath? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375179/java-package-does-not-exist-error

Comment: I couldn't tell you. I've written in Java before but it's far from my forte. I can try looking in to that.

Comment: @DuncanJones Oh man, don't I feel silly lol If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for exposing my ignorance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you've missed a directory from your classpath. Try something like the following:

`java -cp /some/dir/ RunScript.java`

where `/som/dir/` contains the definition of the package you need.