# Android Studio library "error: package does not exist"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have created Android library as Android Studio module. Added as dependency to my root module. While coding I can import any class from library package but while I'm trying run the application I'm getting an error `package some.mylibrary.project does not exist`.

**build.gradle** root module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile project(':libraries:mylibrary')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    ***
}
```

**build.gradle** library module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

     *****    
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':libraries:mylibrary'
```

P.S. I have to mention that the project was exported from Eclipse IDE so the project structure is different from default one.

Answer (score 17):

**For Android Studio 2.2.2**

Yes, in library module, it can't use the apply plugin: `com.android.application` statement in the module definition, yes, use apply plugin: `com.android.library` instead. (still in lib module)

But then you have to do the following:

1. Expose the same SDK versions in Gradle files for both modules.
2. Right click on your projects "app" module folder and click on -> open module settings
3. Click on the "dependencies" tab
4. Click on the + sign to add a new dependency and select "Module Dependency"
5. Look for the library you need and add it.

Also while naming your lib module avoid capitals.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a library module, it can't use the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` statement in the module definition, or the build will silently fail as you're seeing. use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` instead.

A bug has been filed to request that the build system fail loudly instead of silently when this happens: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76725

Comment: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

Comment: Hmm, this error occurs for me in my library module.  It does not use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

The answer above is somewhat lacking
If you project java add in Kotlin getting get this error

- Tools Tab Kotlin and Configure Kotlin
- (Select Android with Gradle) after select with Modules

**Project build.gradle add**

```
ext.kotlin_version = ‘1.3.21’
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

**Apps build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

**Kotlin**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Referance : https://medium.com/mindorks/enabling-kotlin-support-for-a-current-only-java-android-project-98c75e04384a

Comment: Note that `'kotlin-android'` should be applied before `'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Answer (score 3):

in my case kotlin-android plugin was missed in module build.gradle file

```
// Inside each module using kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

Please see more details in [Add Kotlin to an existing app doc](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#groovy)

Comment: Yes, this issue I faced today

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you change the package name and try to run the code. this occurs because the android studio still has the cache of your package with an old name.

Also, cross-check all the imports as well as an imported package in your code so that no different package name exists. For example, is common this error is referring to another imported file near where the error is occurring. Check previous imports near.

**To fix this error** you can try to do an 'invalidate caches / Restart' option from the File menu in android studio. Choose “Invalidate and restart option” and close Android Studio.

Another reason for this error, is when one changes the project's path  root folder or in any of the modules it depends. In this particular case, **to fix this error** you need to remove the affected modules, and re-add them again. Next don't forget to do an 'invalidate caches / Restart' option from the File menu in android studio. Choose “Invalidate and restart option” and close Android Studio.

**Clean your project from android studio :**

- “Build -> Clean Project”. This will clear your build folders.
- Remove your .gradle directory from the root of your project. It contains some Gradle cache files.
- Delete also the .idea directory (make a backup before). It contains some project configuration files.

Restart Android Studio.

**Finally**

if the error still persists, you need to move the affected files to an external directory of the project's root folder. And on Android Studio, create manually each filename as previous, and copy the code inside from the old file. **This will defiantly solve this error.**

Answer (score 1):

In build-gradle app, add this row:

```
implementation project(":your_name_library_here")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue while using **Kotlin** and have

```
kotlin.incremental=true
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

in the **gradle.properties**, then you need to remove this temporarily to fix the build.

After the successful build, you can again add these properties to speed up the build time while using Kotlin.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951797/3948854