# Android Studio cannot access the function in the other class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the class A with the public function "go()" in the module_A,when I use the A a=new A() in the module_B,
It work well.but when I call the function "a.go()",the android studio write the error message that you cannot access the package "xxxxxxxxx";

In the module_B,I have write the compile project(":module_A") in the build.gradle file;

Comment: module_B needs the same dependency as module_A
In "go()" Range

Answer (score 16):

Rebuild your module. Then if it didn't work you can use `Invalidate Caches/ Restart` in `File` menu of `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error you can try to do an 'invalidate caches / Restart' option from the File menu in android studio. Choose “Invalidate and restart option” and close Android Studio.

Additionally, check the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68736360/13794189