# Error while compiling the kotlin program in IDEA

Tags: kotlin

I got an error while compiling the kotlin program in IDEA, as shown below：

Error: Kotlin: Kotlin home does not exist or is not a directory: D:\JavaProgram\JetBrains\kotlin.

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
killall java
./gradlew clean assemble
```

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48890533/6169668)

Comment: I tried, No, I can only copy the kotlin in the idea plug-in directory to D:\JavaProgram\JetBrains\.