# Can't import a sub package in java

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this problem?:

I can't import a sub package, when I try  `javac Pixel.java` I get:

> Pixel.java:2: error: package image.color does not exist.

I also tried `import image.*` and `import image.color.*;`.

Pixel.java:

```
package image;

import image.color.GrayColor;

public class Pixel{
}
```

GrayColor.java:

```
package image.color;

public class GrayColor{
}
```

My tree:
`└── image`
    `├── Pixel.java`
    `├── color`
        `├── GrayColor.class`
        `└── GrayColor.java`

Comment: Remove image from image.color.* and try again

Comment: `javac Pixel.java` is incorrect. Usually, you would do `javac image/Pixel.java` from the parent folder, but you can also do `javac -cp .. Pixel.java` from the `image` folder.

Comment: Duplicate of [Java Package Does Not Exist Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6375179/5221149).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you are not compiling `Pixel.java` from the root directory of the project, and you compile it from within the directory where that file is located (`image/`). In this case, directory structure matching your package declaration `image/color` is not available from `image/`, as you do not have `image/image/color`.

Package declarations must match the directory structure they are declared in, relatively to the root directory, as they are looked up *relatively* to the project's root directory. E.g. if you are compiling `A.java`, which has a dependency `B.java` (A imports B) defined under the `package a.b;`, then the `B.java` will be looked up in the corresponding `a/b/` folder, and if you are in the folder, **from where**, `a/b/` is not available, compiler will complain, that it cannot find the package/directory `a/b/`.

You have two ways to solve this when using `javac`:

- Best is to compile your file(s) from the root directory. This way, all the package declarations will match the directory structure (assuming your package names are correct and they match directory names) relatively from your root directory;
- You can use `-cp` flag, to tell to the Java compiler where to look for other sources, in case you are *not* compiling your file(s) from the root directory of your project. Note, that here, as well, you should provide a path of the root directory of your project, as the class(es) package(s) will only match the folder structure, when looked up from the root directory of the project.