# React native: MainApplication.java "new architecture doesn't exist"

Tags: android, react-native, apple-m1

Environment:
Mac Pro M1 chip
react native cli installed
SDK for android installed and updated
Android platform 30, 31 installed

Error displayings:
MainApplication.java (6 erros)

[image]

Have tried cleaning caches with the following and building again

1.react-native start –reset-cache
2.  watchman watch-del-all
3. rm -rf  ~/.gradle/caches/

Im stuck at this moment. I would truly appreciate some help.

Comment: I found a similar problem for you,i hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375179/java-package-does-not-exist-error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error during upgrade of react native to 0.68. The problem was that some of the new packages and files needed for the upgrade which contains the "new architecture" were not included.

I'd recommend following the react native upgrade tool to make sure all the proper files are created and added to the right locations:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.4&to=0.68.0